# Excel: Display the excel popup programmatically via python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, vba

I am programmatically creating a copying an VBA enabled excel spreadsheet and opening the excel and clicking a button names **Create** to create some data,

```
import os, os.path
import win32com.client

if os.path.exists('excel.xlsm'):
   xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
   xl.DisplayAlerts = False
   xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath('excel.xlsm'), ReadOnly=1)
   tTemp = 'excel.xlsm'+'!'+'ThisWorkbook.Create'
   xl.Application.Run(tTemp)
   xl.Application.Quit() # Comment this out if your excel script closes
   del xl
```

So whenever the workbook opens, i am getting the below popup which i had to manually click on OK
[image]

Is there a way to disable this popup or a way to programmatically handle this popup.

Thanks,

Comment: That looks like a `MsgBox` within the VBA. My best bet would be to add an optional parameter to `Create` specifying whether or not to display it.

Comment: @BigBen, Is there a way to programmatically click the OK button instead of changing the VBA code?

Comment: Not easily, no.

Comment: I agree with @BigBen that in general it makes more sense to simply add an argument in VBA sub like true of false that will determine if MsgBox should appear. Nonetheless, there is still an ugly way to programmatically click OK button: you can use ```import pyautogui pyautogui.press('enter')```. The tricky part is to time it. Also another library can help you - pywinauto. It can search for the OK button ID and can press this button for you, it's more flexible and allows various configurations.